# How to dynamically change icon in lightning tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to change the icon in the lightning tab based on the event in the child component. I tried the below two approaches and it is not working. Can you please assist.

Approach 1

### Component

`<lightning:tab label='Monthly Income And Expenditure' id='incAndExp' iconName='{!v.iconName}'>`

### Controller

```
component.set('v.iconName','utility:edit');
```

Approach 2

### Controller

```
component.find('incAndExp').set('v.iconName','utility:edit');
```

Comment: I have already tried the below approach and this reloads tab and the child components in the tab. So this will not work for us.                                                                                    https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235870/cant-dynamically-change-label-of-lightningtab

Comment: You can have a boolean attribute on the parent component and feed it into the child, which will set the value based on your specified logic. Then in your `lightning:tab` you can do `iconName="{!v.someBoolean ? 'utility:edit' : 'some other icon'}"`.

Comment: Hi vinny. I actually went debugging on the answer you've linked to before posting that answer. Unless the situation has changed, the problem still remains. The component expects its parameters upfront, during the initial rendering process. As such, you have to completely un-render and re-render the component to get changes to appear. The properties are *not* reactive and can't simply be changed. This is a limitation of the platform, not anything you're doing wrong. There's also no "workaround" aside from re-rendering. You'd have to write your own component.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. Is the behaviour same in LWC also?

Comment: How can I do the unsaved warning tab using aura component as shown in LDS. https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tabs/#JavaScript-Needs

Comment: This works as expected in LWC. But LWC tab can not contain aura components.